# How to style markers for Cluster features and normal features differently in OpenLayers 3.x

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I can style the marker for the clustered source items but when there is no clustering I'd like to display the features original marker. How can that be achieved?

Comment: It's hard to tell! You didn't show any code.

Comment: You are right, I will add some to make it more clear!